# Use a common modal for different scenarios on the entire web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, popup

I am opening a modal on the click of different elements(buttons) on my webpage.

Is there a way to have only one modal, and control its view depending on which element it is being triggered from?

Each modal is going to have different content displayed.

For example,

- Modal A will display a form consisting of 10 different fields
- Modal B will display a "Thank you" message
- Modal C will display another form consisting of just 3 fields

Different buttons trigger different modals.

I was hoping to have the code for the common modal be placed at the start of the body, and somehow alter its view using Javascript. But I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If then can you please share the code?

Comment: @ENUENAN Nope. I ended up using https://jquerymodal.com/
Check it out though, it may come in handy

Comment: Same. Need the tools that can rule modals by  different scenarios and logics